# cassandra udt: when adding a new field into udt type, columns only shows old udt type data

Tags: cassandra

I have created a udt type in cassandra.
--> member(name text).

Then I create a table "users" and one of columns "members" is list>.

I add an another field age into type user
So now is member(name text, age int).

I insert data [{name: 'james', age: 1}] into table "users". But it only shows [{name:'james'}] when I do a query.
I have run DESC KEYSPACE, and the type is exactly as member(name text, age int). Any suggestions?

PS: my cassandra version is 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug ([CASSANDRA-9188](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9188)). You need to restart your cqlsh session to make it use the latest type definition.

Comment: Hi stafan, it was solved. But the first time when I quit cqlsh session, it still does not work. Then I tried second time, it works. BTW, I have also tried nodetool clearsnapshots.