# On Cassandra, I get 'comparators do not match or are not compatible' when attempting to append a field to a type

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    version int,
    cats list<frozen<CatId>>,
);


CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS dog (
    dog_id bigint,
);

ALTER TABLE abc ADD dog list<frozen<dog>>;

ALTER TYPE dog ADD food text;
```

This Cassandra migration will yield

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidConfigurationInQueryException: comparators do not match or are not compatible.
```

I tried to looks this up and already saw [cassandra udt: when adding a new field into udt type, columns only shows old udt type data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665381/cassandra-udt-when-adding-a-new-field-into-udt-type-columns-only-shows-old-udt)

I restarted C* and it still yielded no results. This is Cassandra 4.8.10 btw.

Comment: Btw, this only occurs when the Type was previously dropped and recreated in a previous migration. When I attempt to append a field to another Type that was never dropped, I don't get this error.

Comment: when you recreated data type, did you have a tables that still used it?